# looking for a specialized numpy function to avoid using multiple list comprehension

Tags: python, numpy

I'm not very good at math, numpy and, while i am an experienced coder, i am still a beginner at python.

I have this function that take a small np.array (< 100 elements),
called 100000+ times.

It take 23~25% total cpu time using numpy (whole program profiling in pycharm) :

```
def call(self, _input):
    output = np.array([_input[i] * self.weights[i] for i in range(len(self.weights))]) # <- 4.5% on <listcomp>
    output += self.bias
    output = np.array([np.sum(output[:, i]) for i in range(len(self.weights[0]))]) # <- slowest (11% total, 9.8% on sum)
    output = np.array([self.activation(val) for val in output]) # <- 2.9% on <listcomp>, it's fine.
    self.output = output
    return output
```

It take 17~19% cpu time without numpy (sum take comparatively more cpu than np.sum but it's still a win) :

```
def call(self, _input):
    output = [_input[i] * self.weights[i] for i in range(len(self.weights))]
    output += self.bias
    output = [sum(output[:, i]) for i in range(len(self.weights[0]))]
    output = [self.activation(val) for val in output]
    self.output = output
    return output
```

The problem with my numpy version is, probably, that i take a np.array, make it a list comprehension, make a np.array again, then take this np.array, make it a list comprehension again, then a np.array again, and so on. And converting back an forth on such a tiny array isn't worth it.

Can the numpy version be optimized ? The code is messed up. There might be some kind of specialized numpy map/reduce function somewhere specialized for this.

Comment: or perhaps the array is too small for numpy, i don't know.

Comment: i originally tried dtype=float16, hoping for some auto-vectorization to take place but gained nothing and then it stayed here

Comment: Does `_input * self.weights` work?

Comment: @hpaulj no : ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (8,) (8,16)

Comment: You should specify the `shape` of the relevant arrays if you want us to help write better numpy code.  `_input[:,None] * self.weights` should take care of the broadcasting error.  Have you read enough `numpy` to know what it means by broadcasting?

Comment: @hpaulj i can make an educated guess but no, i haven't, and i will.

Comment: @hpaulj ok i understand my problem now : at some point in the runtime the _input and the weight have different length and 1) it's weird, 2) nothing can work until in cleaned my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After learning about broadcasting, this is how i solved it :

```
    output = np.sum(_input[:,None] * self.weights + self.bias, axis=0)
    output = np.fromiter((self.activation(val) for val in output), dtype=np.single)
```

Comment: Perhaps you can add one more decorator `@njit` to make it smoother, you can look for `numba`